# cakephp, How to pass value to session when click to link?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

There are four branches in my project, when i click branch1 the session should store branch1, the same way to branch 2,3...

```
<?php foreach($val as $value) {?>

<tr>
<th><span><?php echo $this->Html->link($value['Branch']['branch_name'], array('controller' => 'branchs', 'action' => 'index','onclick'=> 'update')) ?></span></th>
<?php  CakeSession::write('sa',$value['Branch']['branch_name']); ?>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
<tr>
```

Comment: you should use this $this->Session->write('sa',$value['Branch']['branch_name']);

Comment: This will give only the last row value, for example branch 5 value will be displayed even if i click branch1

Comment: you make `sa` variable as a random than it will work.

Comment: Yes you can post your answer

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php foreach($val as $value) {?>
<tr>
  <th><span>
  <?php echo $this->Html->link($value['Branch']['branch_name'],array('controller' => 'branchs', 'action' => 'index','onclick'=> 'update')) ?></span>
</th>
<?php  $this->Session->write('sa',$value['Branch']['branch_name']; ?>
 </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

> My demo code

```
$val=array('1','3','4');
        foreach ($val as $key => $value) {
            $this->Session->write('sa',$val);
        }
        $val1=$this->Session->read('sa');
        foreach ($val1 as $key => $value) {
            echo $value.'<br>';
        }
```

> My demo output
>   [image]

Comment: thank you its very clear code.how i can get  $val array values,just say, when i click one link that time value must store in that $val array.